# Laravel: Custom Libraries Don't Work on server

Tags: php, laravel, libraries

I am developing a Laravel Application and I created a custom class named `Date`. This class was placed in `app/libraries/date.php`. In the file `app/start/global.php` I put the following line:

```
app_path().'/libraries',
```

On my localhost server all works, but on my remote server all works also except pages which use this class.

The following error is displayed:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'Date' not found
```

Important: I don't have SSH access to my server. The deploy was taken manually, uploading the files via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel without SSH access is not quite possible as you need composer. If you have some sort of composer manager you should dump it's autoload. **But...**

### What you're doing is awfully bad practice!

Custom classes should be developed using workbench for beginners or manually by advanced coders in the central /vendor or /workbench locations and nowhere else. You should take a look at Laravel's documentation on how to develop a package: [Laravel documentation - Package development](http://laravel.com/docs/packages)

Comment: Thank you! I had already done another publication without SSH, but in another application I wore no custom class.

Comment: I am saying you should most develop classes the right way - change styles right now, this is your opportunity to become a better developer and to make everything smoother in the long run. It's all about good practice in development.

Comment: Yes, I will read the documentation, I have some bad practices because I'm starting at Laravel and before I used the CodeIgniter which is less rigid as standards :(